# Re-ownership of scheduled job from managed packages

Tags: managed-package, scheduled-apex, user-management

One of my orgs has a managed package in it, and was installed by a previous user, who has now been deactivated. Firstly therefore, this means I notice that on the package detail page, it is "Installed by" InactiveUser3, as you see here:

[image: inactive user]

This is fine, however, the managed package comes with a scheduled job, which is listed as being submitted "by" this user, and now, with them deactivated, it is failing and sending an error e-mail along the lines of

Subject

> Developer script exception '<unknown>' : Inactive User yyyyyyyyyyy

and body

> Failed to process batch for class '<unknown>' for job id xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

I have deduced (using the IDs) that it is this scheduled Apex class/user situation causing this error message. So my question is, how do I "reown" the scheduled job?

Under the Scheduled Jobs view, I can see, and "Manage" and "Delete" the job, and I can see the inactive user as the Submitter, but I can't "move" the job to a new active user...? Under manage, I can just change the timings of it all. (and indeed there is no save button either, as I thought changing the details might make me the new owner)

[image: Scheduled Apex]

Surely I am not going to have to uninstall the package and re-install it am I? That could be a catastrophe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you test if you can schedule a new copy of the job from the Apex Classes -> Schedule Apex screen?

If so, you can go ahead and delete this schedule and reschedule the job at the same date/time.

If that's not possible, this is more like a design error from the managed package provider that they should resolve..

Comment: Crickey. Sometimes the simplest solution is the right one. That appears to have done exactly what I would expect (I'll let you know tomorrow if it fails!). Must be Friday. Cheers.

Comment: Glad I could be of help!

Comment: One note that it's possible to have jobs that have some additional context or use a cron expression instead of the graphical scheduler UI. In both cases this wouldn't work, but this seems to be the "happy path" for most cases.